# Why does looping through a fetch API response give undefined results?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I am trying to dynamically add objects from a json file to my HTML file. For some reason, when looping through the fetched json file, the properties of objects are undefined. Logging the entire json file into console works, the problem appears looping through the file for some reason. I have double checked, the title and body properties do exist for the json objects.

Here's the Javascript file:

```js
window.onload = function() {

    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(json => {
            console.log(json); // console output shows the objects fine

            for (post in json) {
                console.log(post.title);
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                var title = document.createElement('h1');
                var body = document.createElement('p');
                
                title.innerText = post.title;
                body.innerText = post.body;

                div.appendChild(title);
                div.appendChild(body);
                document.body.appendChild(div);
            }
        })

}
```

Here's the HTML file:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="res/css/style.css">
    <title>Lecture 7 - JS-4</title>


</head>

<body>

    <h1> Fetch API</h1>


</body>

</html>
```

This is what the page looks like:
[image]

I have searched online and in most cases, the problem seems to be that the function fetching the data does not return anything. However, as I am not asking for the value of the function, this doesn't appear to be the problem in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the for loop is wrong

try

```
for (const post of json) {...}
```

instead of

```
for (post in json) {...}
```

the `for..of` loop iterates over values while the `for..in` loop iterates over indices (for some strange legacy reasons)

also don't forget `const` or `let` since you introduce a new variable/constant called `post` inside the loop

Comment: @ahyes don't use `var`, it is kind of old style and has some issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var
you should always go for `const`, and only use `let` if REALLY needed.
in big projects like 100K LOC, I've typically a 20:1 ratio between `const` and `let`, and zero vars

Answer (score 1):

Use `of` instead of `in`

```js
for (post of json) {
```